# Exclude matches in Chrome extension manifest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, pattern-matching, manifest.json

In `content_script` options of my extension's `manifest.json`:

```
{
            "matches": [
                "*://*.pipedrive.com/*"
            ],
            "exclude_globs": [
                "://www.pipedrive.com/*"
            ],
            "css": [
                "content/callbox.css",
                "content/pipedrive/pipedrive.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "assets/js/jssip-2.0.6.min.js",
                "content/message.js",
                "content/callbox.js",
                "content/pipedrive/pipedrive.js"
            ]
        }
```

I want these scripts run in subdomain of pipedrive excluding the main homepage (`www.pipedrive.com`), both `exclude_globs` and `exclude_matches` do not work, these scripts still run in `www.pipedrive.com`. How can I make it?

Comment: `"exclude_matches":["*://www.pipedrive.com/*"]` ... see the `*` before `://` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I lacked the `*` before `://` in `exclude_globs`